# Is there a pytest hook, which is executed before __exit__ method of context manager?

Tags: python, pytest

My task is to make screenshot on exception.
Since I'm using context manager to enter session I need screenshot to be taken before `__exit__` method of context manager (before exit out of session). Hooks that I've found for pytest are executed after `__exit__`. Is there some hook that I don't know that is executed on exception before `__exit__`?

I've tried `pytest_runtest_teardown`, `pytest_runtest_makereport`, etc.

Thanks

Comment: You could write a decorator for your test functions that will take a screen shot when there is an exception and then re raise it.

Comment: yeah, but I would have to repeat it over and over again for each test function. I've found better solution: screenshot in __exit__ if using context manager or in pytest_runtest_makereport if without context manager. So I would have to mention it just two times for all test cases. But now I'm searching for the best solution, where I have to write it just one time.